Why does the following recursive function not use the values in the cache to return the values?
I have created a python function to calculate the n-th fibonacci term. To increase the efficiency, I have used a cache_mem dict to store the variable. When I debugged the function, it is going through all function calls instead of using the stored variables of the cache. Why s this happening ?
cache_mem = {}

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        cache_mem[n-1] = cache_mem.get(n-1, fib(n-1))
        cache_mem[n-2] = cache_mem.get(n-2, fib(n-2))

        return cache_mem[n-1] + cache_mem[n-2]

I expect the cache_mem dict to store the values of the results, and use them instead of calling the function. Based on my understanding, the line
cache_mem[n-1] = cache_mem.get(n-1, fib(n-1))

will check for the value for n-1 in the dict. If it  exists, it will return the value, else it will calculate the values.

The arguments to a function are all evaluated before calling the function. So when you write
cache_mem.get(n-1, fib(n-1))

it first has to execute fib(n-1) before calling cache_mem.get(). So the cache never prevents making the call.
Replace that with an explicit condition:
if n-1 not in cache_mem:
    cache_mem[n-1] = fib(n-1)

BTW, Python has a functools.cache decorator to add automatic caching to a function.

At no point in your code do you break off recursive calls based on whether the elements are in the cache. There needs to be a check along the lines of "if we've already computed this n, return it without recursing":
cache_mem = {}

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    elif n in cache_mem:
        return cache_mem[n]

    cache_mem[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    return cache_mem[n]


print(fib(933))

Notice how the logic works based on n, not n - 1 and n - 2. Let the recursive calls handle those cases. It's a common antipattern in recursion to worry about child calls in the parent frame.
Better yet, use the @functools.cache decorator to avoid having to explicitly memoize, or avoid recursion, which is a poor solution to this problem (it can't handle values of n larger than ~1k in CPython even with caching, adds overhead and uses a good deal of memory).

In the get method, python evaluates the fib function first and then calls the get method with the result of the fib call. Instead of using default value method, first check if key exists, if true return from dict else evaluate recursive call
